# GSON MD5 sum does not match - How to compute MD5?

Tags: java, gson

I wanted to use the GSON library to parse JSON content. I downloaded it from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar and then I tried to verify its MD5. However it doesn't match. What am I doing wrong?

From the website (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar.asc.md5), the MD5 *should be*:

```
8e1ecea2d92b9ba3e594bdbb5fd79845
```

But when I compute it locally I get:

```
$ md5sum gson-2.8.5.jar 
089104cb90d8b4e1aa00b1f5faef0742  gson-2.8.5.jar
```

They are different. Should I use this library or is it corrupted?

Comment: Use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar.md5, thats the correct md5 hash

Comment: Oh... wrong MD5 file. Thank you.